# How to evaluate Riemann Zeta function

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, riemann-zeta

How do I evaluate this function for given $s$?

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^s} = \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \cdots$$

Comment: Do you mean numerically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about numerical evaluation, along the critical strip $0<\Re s<1$ and "large" $\Im s$, (which is the region of interest for many) the [Riemann-Siegel formula](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-309-02/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2.pdf) is standard; off the strip, what you can manage is a polyalgorithm.

For $\Re s\leq0$, one can use the reflection formula for $\zeta$,

$$\zeta(1-s)=\frac{2}{(2\pi)^s}\cos\left(\frac{s\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$$

so we can consider evaluation for $\Re s>0$ in what follows.

Note that if $|s|$ is "large enough" (how large is "large" depends on the computing environment you're in), one can simply use the defining series $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty j^{-s}$, since its terms quickly diminish in magnitude. That leaves the problem of what to do for small to medium-sized $s$.

The key is to use the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html):

$$\eta(s):=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j^s}$$

which is related to $\zeta$ by the following identity:

$$\eta(s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)$$

The reason for our interest in $\eta$ is that although this sum is slowly convergent, it is an alternating series, and a number of algorithms exist for quickly finding the sum of an alternating series numerically.

One method is the [Levin transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6625); another one, which is one of the simplest methods for numerically summing alternating series (and my personal favorite) is the Cohen-Rodriguez Villegas-Zagier algorithm. The algorithm is a bit too long to describe here, so I will just have to point you to the [original paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1046889587).

This is in fact identical to the approach taken by Borwein in this [paper](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P155.pdf).

Comment: In Example 3 (p.6) of the Cohen, Rodriguez, Villegas and Zagier's paper  the values $\zeta (1/2)$ and $\zeta (-1+i)$ of the Riemann zeta function are calculated. "The latter works even though the coefficients $a_{k}$ of our "alternating" series $\sum (-1)^{k}a_{k}$ are not alternating or even real and do not tend to zero."!

Comment: +1 for the Riemann-Siegel formula and Cohen-Rodriguez Villegas-Zagier algorithm.

Comment: Though CRVZ was used for evaluating $\zeta$ at $i-1$ in the paper, some numerical testing I did shows that the method can be unstable for some arguments with negative real part. This is why I recommended using the reflection formula instead for arguments in that region.

Comment: On another note, Maple and *Mathematica* employ Euler-Maclaurin summation for computing $\zeta$; the problem with this of course is that there is the assumption that either you can easily generate or have a large enough cache of Bernoulli numbers (which is not a problem for Maple and *Mathematica*, but may be inconvenient in other environments).

Comment: Yet another note: in fact, due to $\zeta$'s mirror symmetry ($\zeta(\bar{s})=\overline{\zeta(s)}$), one can actually restrict computations so that one is handling only arguments with real and imaginary part both positive.

Comment: Don't you need to have the real part of s, not the modulus, be "large" to use the defining series?

Comment: @castal: I did say "away from the critical strip". :)

Comment: I've read Borwein's paper, but I've had trouble following it.  I sent him an email a few years ago asking him about the following issues but got no response.  First, on page 3, shouldn't the inequality right after "we observe that, by Algorithm 1" have a final integrand with $\left|\log x\right|^{\sigma-1}$ rather than $\left|\log x\right|^{s-1}$?  Second, and more importantly, I don't see how he gets from the estimate "integral ≤ .68" to the following bound on $\left|\gamma_n(s)\right|$.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the work of Wadim Zudilin. In particular you should look at 
["One of the numbers ζ(5), ζ(7), ζ(9), ζ(11) is irrational" (Turpion link, pdf 91k, gzip ps 80k) in Russian Math. Surveys  56:4 (2001), 774--776;](http://wain.mi.ras.ru/PS/zeta5-11%24.pdf)

Comment: I add the work of Tanguy Rivoal on the same subject. For instance this http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0104/0104221v2.pdf (in French).

Comment: There are of course special methods for evaluating $\zeta$ at even (using of course the relation with the Bernoulli numbers) and odd integers. Searching the literature should turn up the methods for $\zeta(2k+1)$.

Comment: @J. Mangaldan Yes, of course. Euler was the first to give the formula for $\zeta(2)$ with several proofs, and as you say $\zeta(2n)$ can be expressed using the Bernoulli numbers $B_\nu$ (was that Euler too?). If someone could add a link it would be good.

Comment: Indeed, it was Euler who computed values at even arguments from 2 to 26; and T.J. Stieltjes later extended these calculations by Euler.

Answer (score 1):

Early implementations are based on variations of the [Riemann-Siegel formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFormula.html). A key figure in the development of numerical algorithms was [Andrew Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/). He wrote two fundamental papers on calculating zeros on the critical line - [Fast algorithms for multiple evaluations of the Riemann zeta function](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-309-02/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2/S0002-9947-1988-0961614-2.pdf) and [Supercomputers and the Riemann zeta function](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/arch/zeta.fn.supercomp.pdf). A bunch of other people (including Alan Turing) have contributed to the verification of the Riemann hypothesis. A good summary is included in [the report](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetazeroscompute.html) by Xavier Gourdon.

More recently, practitioners have been working on improvements to the [Odlyzko–Schönhage algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odlyzko%E2%80%93Sch%C3%B6nhage_algorithm) (also see [here](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetazeros1e13-1e24.pdf)). Two key figures are [Jonathan Bober](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ejb12407/) and [Ghaith Hiary](https://people.math.osu.edu/hiary.1/). Hiary was a PhD student of Odlyzko who works on fast computations of Dirichlet functions (his thesis was on a variation of the Odlyzko–Schönhage algorithm). There is an implementation of the Odlyzko–Schönhage algorithm on [Bober's webpage](https://github.com/jwbober/zetacalc). However, this is fairly difficult to read.

A bunch of students have written there own implementations of the Riemann-Siegel formula. Perhaps the most well known is the [C implementation](https://web.viu.ca/pughg/thesis.d/masters.thesis.pdf) written by [Glen Pugh](https://web.viu.ca/pughg/) (this is sometimes incorrectly cited as his PhD thesis. Glen wrote a wonderful PhD thesis about [Lanzcos Gamma Approximations](https://web.viu.ca/pughg/phdThesis/phdThesis.pdf)). Another computer implementation in [C++](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/six/parallel/2-Final-Report.html#Source) was written by [Ken Takusagawa](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/six/parallel/2-Final-Report.html).

I wrote my [own Riemann-Siegel code](https://github.com/matthewshawnkehoe/Riemann-Zeta-Functions) in Julia. I summarized my findings in [a report](https://matthewshawnkehoe.github.io/files/kehoe_ms_project.pdf) which was later expanded in a [Beamer presentation](https://axion004.files.wordpress.com/2022/12/calculating_zeros_of_the_riemann_zeta_function.pdf).

If you are interested in writing your own implementation then I would suggest reading [Riemann's Zeta Function](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486417409) by Harold M. Edwards. An English translation of Bernhard Riemann's eight-page paper entitled "On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude" is included at the end of the book.