# The series $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{{k}{(k^2+1)}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{{k}{(k^2+1)}}}$$

How can I calculate its exact limit (if that is possible)?

Comment: I think $\zeta(3/2) - \sum_{k = 1}^N \left( \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k^2 + 1)}} \right)$ for sufficiently large N is a reasonable estimate. It gives me something along the lines of 2.2640623991416056.

Comment: I don't think this has a nice closed form. Is this a problem you created, or is it from a problem book?

Comment: @Potato: this problem comes from one of my colleagues. I don't know yet where it comes from.

Comment: Do you know if it has a closed form solution? This seems like a pretty random sum, and we may be chasing unicorns here.

Comment: @Potato: i don't know that. TenaliRaman has offered a pretty nice answer. W|A tells the same.

Comment: @Chris you can also use integral to estimate the sum: $$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2+1)}}$$ Mathematica gives the answer in terms of hypergeometric function: $2 \sqrt{2} \, _2 F_1 \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} ; \frac{5}{4}, -4 \right) \approx 2.3261$ while the sum is around $2.2641$.

Comment: @qoqosz: i think Potato is right that there is no closed form. This problem is nice when you're asked to prove its convergenge, but in this case i see no better way.

Comment: @Chris sure, that's very likely. But even though having a good approximation in nice closed form is worth a shot :)

Comment: @qoqosz: of course! i totally agree with you. Thanks :-)

Comment: Very nice solutuions around! Thanks all (+1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite the sum in terms of the zeta function. 
The resulting sum is alternating, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{{k}{(k^2+1)}}} 
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)^{1/2}} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} 
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{\Gamma(j+\frac{1}{2})}{j!\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} \left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)^j \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{\Gamma(j+\frac{1}{2})}{j!\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{2j+3/2}} \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \underbrace{\frac{(2j)!}{(j!)^2 2^{2j}} 
\textstyle\zeta(2j+\frac{3}{2})}_{a_j}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
In the second step we expanded $(1+1/k^2)^{-1/2}$ in a [binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html).
The last line suggests that there is no nice closed form for the sum.
Unfortunately, the convergence properties of this sum are not much better than the original. 
For large $j$, $a_j \sim 1/\sqrt{j}$, so the sum goes like $\sum_j(-1)^j/\sqrt{j}$.

Let's accelerate the sum using the [Euler transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html).
Then, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{{k}{(k^2+1)}}}
&=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \underbrace{(-1)^n \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} a_{n-k}}_{b_n}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ is not alternating, but has much better convergence properties than the original.
Numerically we find $b_n \sim 1/2^n$.

Below we give the partial sums to $25$ digits. 
$$\begin{array}{ll}
N & \sum_{n=0}^N b_n \\ \hline
   1 & 1.818439778099484176707949 \\
   2 & 2.052201427955914030757063 \\
   4 & 2.214850676717845386847939 \\
   8 & 2.261274490824097920144642 \\
   16 & 2.264052732086094056012626 \\
   32 & 2.264062399012245290957591 \\
   64 & 2.264062399141221028566328 \\
   128 & 2.264062399141221028592305
\end{array}$$

Another good approach suggested by [@qoqosz in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159398/173927#comment367517_159398) is to estimate the sum with an integral.
That estimate can be improved somewhat by applying the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).
The resulting asymptotic series gets us four digits before it starts to diverge.

Comment: that's very impressive! Thank you! :-)

Comment: You might want to expand the argument leading to $b_n\sim1/2^n$ (at present, the invocation of de Moivre is rather mysterious).

Comment: @Chris: Glad to help.

Comment: @did: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.

Comment: @did: Thanks, I had a closer look at the argument for the $b_n$s and it was not sound. Numerically the terms go like $1/2^n$, as claimed. I'll try and cook up an argument for it. I appreciate your close reading.

Comment: @oen: You can also take a hybrid path that starts like yours (expanding $\frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1}}$ using power series) and then uses the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to sum that. I did this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/173981).

Comment: @robjohn: I had a look at your answer earlier and upvoted it, of course! Very clever use of Euler-Maclaurin.

Answer (score 9):

Using the binomial theorem to expand
$$
\begin{align}
{\small\frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1)}}}
&=k^{-3/2}\left(1+\frac1{k^2}\right)^{-1/2}\\
&\sim k^{-3/2}-\frac12k^{-7/2}+\frac38k^{-11/2}-\frac5{16}k^{-15/2}+\frac{35}{128}k^{-19/2}-\frac{63}{256}k^{-23/2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
with an error of approximately $\frac14k^{-27/2}$.

Applying the Euler Maclaurin Sum Formula to $(1)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n{\small\frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1)}}}
&\sim C-2n^{-1/2}+\frac12n^{-3/2}+\frac3{40}n^{-5/2}-\frac14n^{-7/2}+\frac{31}{384}n^{-9/2}+\frac3{16}n^{-11/2}\\
&-\frac{12959}{66560}n^{-13/2}-\frac5{32}n^{-15/2}+\frac{214861}{557056}n^{-17/2}+\frac{35}{256}n^{-19/2}\\[6pt]
&-\frac{24553421}{27525120}n^{-21/2}-\frac{63}{512}n^{-23/2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
with an error of approximately $3n^{-25/2}$. Since the series is convergent, $C$ represents the sum.

Computing the partial sum to $n=100$ and using $(2)$ to compute $C$, we get
$$
C\stackrel{.}{=}2.264062399141221028592305
$$
Just as a check, with $n=1000$, $(2)$ gives
$$
C\stackrel{.}{=}2.264062399141221028592304976971183194
$$

Comment: The powerful Euler Maclaurin Sum Formula again at work! :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here is another possible approach for *numerically* summing this series. Through Laplace transform methods, we find that

$$\frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty \exp(-ku)\sqrt{u}\,J_{-\frac14}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)J_{\frac14}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\mathrm du$$

where $J_\nu(u)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. Substituting this into the summation expression, interchanging summation and integration, and some finagling yields the integral expression

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1)}}=2\sqrt\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\exp(2t)-1} J_{-\frac14}(t) J_{\frac14}(t)\mathrm dt$$

Oscillatory integrals such as the one given above can be treated as alternating series; if you look at a plot of the integrand, you can see that the integral across the zeroes of the function alternate between positive and negative signs. Thus, letting $t_k$ be the $k$-th zero of the function $J_{-\frac14}(t) J_{\frac14}(t)$, we consider the series

$$2\sqrt\pi\left(\int_0^{t_1} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\exp(2t)-1} J_{-\frac14}(t) J_{\frac14}(t)\mathrm dt+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\exp(2t)-1} J_{-\frac14}(t) J_{\frac14}(t)\mathrm dt\right)$$

(This strategy for numerically evaluating oscillatory integrals is due to [Longman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S030500410003187X).)

We can use a computing environment like *Mathematica* to generate the $t_k$:

\begin{array}{c|c}k&t_k\\\hline 1&2.006299672\\2&2.780887724\\3&5.123062743\\ 4&5.906142699\\5&8.257951176\\6&9.042383664\end{array}

One could use the Euler transform as in oen's answer to sum the alternating series, but the terms decrease rather quickly in magnitude that even direct summation works fine. Letting $S_k$ be the $k$-th partial sum, we have

\begin{array}{c|c}k&S_k\\\hline 1&2.2642181990016\\2&2.2632428613646\\3&2.2640625078551\\ 4&2.2640612519867\\5&2.2640623992549\\6&2.2640623973568\end{array}

The last approximation is already good to eight digits. Taking more terms of the series, we have, to twenty digits

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{k(k^2+1)}}\approx 2.26406239914122102859$$

Thirteen terms were needed to obtain this approximation.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't think of going this way. (+1)

Comment: It's nice to have so many ways to sum things numerically. Using Laplace Tranforms is neat (+1) :-)

Comment: By the way, Longman's way was a new way for me, but now it's not new anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

I might as well... as mentioned by oen in his answer, the series

$$\mathscr{S}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(-\frac14\right)^j\binom{2j}{j}\zeta\left(2j+\frac32\right)$$

is alternating, but rather slowly convergent. oen used the Euler transformation for accelerating the convergence of this series in his answer; for this answer, I will be using the [Levin $t$-transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7030):

$$\mathcal{L}_n=\frac{\sum\limits_{j=0}^n (-1)^j\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^{n-1}\frac{S_j}{a_j}}{\sum\limits_{j=0}^n (-1)^j\binom{n}{j}(j+1)^{n-1}\frac1{a_j}}$$

where $a_j$ is the $j$-th term of the series, and $S_j$ is the $j$-th partial sum.

To demonstrate the superior convergence properties of the $t$-transform, consider the following evaluations:

\begin{array}{c|cc}k&\mathcal{L}_k&|\mathscr{S}-\mathcal{L}_k|\\\hline 2&2.2593704308006952815&4.692\times10^{-3}\\5&2.2640560757360687322&6.323\times10^{-6}\\10&2.2640623990222550236&1.189\times10^{-10}\\15&2.2640623991414400190&2.190\times10^{-13}\\20&2.2640623991412210238&4.828\times10^{-18}\\25&2.2640623991412210286&5.938\times10^{-21}\end{array}

Thirty terms of the series along with the $t$-transform gives a result good to twenty-five digits, compared to the $128$ terms required by the Euler transform.

Comment: I like a lot to see so many different ways to go. However, some things here are completely new for me (Levin t-transform). Thanks!

Comment: That's the thing about the good math problems; there's always more than one way to solve them.

Comment: @J.M.: The other day I happened to be reading one of your answers that used the Levin transform and wondered if it might show up here! A very powerful method. (+1)

Comment: Thanks @oen, I've been actually looking for an excuse to use the Levin transform for a while...

Answer (score 0):

With this general formula can be computed a large number of digits.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{p}f(n)+\sum_{k=0}^{g(p)}\frac{2\cdot _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{4},k+\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{-1}{(p+1)^2}\right)\cdot B_{2k}\cdot \Gamma(2k+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \Gamma(2k+1)\cdot (p+1)^{\frac{4k+1}{2}}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(p+1)((p+1)^2+1)}}$

Example for p=20 g(20)=35 we have:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=2.2640623991412210285923049769711831944250989137549753245$ ,with 55 decimals.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h3020964p27396207