# hard Evaluation Numerically Double Sum

Tags: calculus

I try to compare several method of sum acceleration series and  testing in the following Double sum
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} \log ^2(j+k+1)=-0.00652533458496$$ (Ithink this is the true Value but here begin the troubles Mathematica gives the values using WynnEpsilon complexInfinity and if I Use levinUtrasform I get 5.1729515919603532132234865492317838383764158033761822568
and Maple gives nothing , if I change the values I get (using my method)
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)^{j+k} \log ^2(j+k+1)=-0.087178770080932$$ Maples gives 1.05795918367346939 , Mathematica gives 0.020656409926403872149 and the levinUtrasform -0.087178770080932183760585045710101
could you show what values are correct ??

Comment: What is the LevinUTransform ?

Comment: How does the double series converge when for each $k$, the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^{j+k} \log^2(j+k+1)$ diverges?

Comment: This question, like your past questions, are non motivated (why are you interested in this sum ? What is you knowledge on it ; you probably already have track ?). Give us context, what you know, what you don't want, etc. My recent experience with one of the last questions you have asked was an extreme difficulty to communicate exactly what you wanted.

Comment: the Levin u-transformation is mentioned as a good universal technique for convergence acceleration. .the series$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } (-1)^{j+k} \log (j+1) \log (k+1)=0.050981734929135662$$ converge

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/levins-u-transformation

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I wasn't aware of them because you hadn't prefixed them by @ followed by my pseudo.