# Riemann Zeta Function numeric computing clarification

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-zeta

I want to implement Riemann Zeta function in some programming language and I try to use algorithms from this question

[Modern formula for calculating Riemann Zeta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183680/modern-formula-for-calculating-riemann-zeta-function)

I have 2 questions:

1. I cannot find what does it means: $$e_{k}=\sum_{j=k}^{n}\left ( _{a}^{b}  \right )$$

most probably it is my lack of math knowledge. Is it well-known polynomial or what?

2. How to calculate $$\epsilon_{n}(s)$$ if they define it like this $$\left | \epsilon_{n}(s) \right |\leqslant something$$ How can I calculate it? I need exact formula for $$\epsilon_{n}(s) = something$$ I cannot use inequality and I cannot use formula for absolute value for numeric calculations.

Comment: $$e_{k}=\sum_{j=k}^{n}\left ( _{a}^{b}  \right )={b \choose a}+\cdots +{b \choose a},$$ where ${b \choose a}=b!/a!(b-a)!$.

Comment: I assume $\binom ba$ is a binomial coefficient.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms) for the correct useful formulas